# Undefined font shape in chapter title

Tags: fonts, pdftex, chapters

I'm getting a `Font shape '...' undefined` in a *very specific* setup, and I have no clue why. Here is an MWE.

The following code **does not** result in a warning. However, when you change `\lipsum[1-3]` to `\lipsum[1-4]`, the first page is full, and somehow this triggers it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{LobsterTwo}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{lmr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{\LobsterTwo Test}
\lipsum[1-3] % change this line to \lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

The idea is to have a default `lmodern` font, but also to highlight some special words in the chapter title with the `LobsterTwo` font. The full warning is `Font shape 'OT1/LBSTR-LF/m/sl' undefined(Font) using 'OT1/cmr/m/n' instead`. I'm using `pdflatex`.

Note that I actually don't see a problem in the output, but I don't think ignoring warnings is ever a good idea, so I want to understand why this is happening and how it can be resolved.

Comment: your document class is selecting a slanted font style and the font you have chosen does not have slanted and has no substitution specified so you are getting the default computer modern font

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My first guess too, but that doesn't explain why there is only a warning when the first page is full. I.e., see the difference for `\lipsum[1-3]` and `\lipsum[1-4]`. There must be something more at play.

Comment: @Safron The page header! The `book` class uses slanted type for it. Use `fancyhdr` to fix the headers.

Comment: as egreg says it is the page header, but also the issue is really that the lobster package is changing all the font setup then you are doing `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{lmr}` which sets the default font to latin modern so most of the settings are now wrong, and the font choices are broken so falling back on neither lobster2 nor latin modern but the emergency default of computer modern.  what exactly do you want to happen here (you should never have font commands in the argument of \chapter, the section heading design  should  be in the document setup not the text argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is issued when a second page is produced because the `book` class uses slanted type and uppercase for the page headers.

Since `\LobsterTwo` is simply defined as

```
\def\LobsterTwofamily{Lbstr-LF}
\newcommand*\LobsterTwo{\fontfamily{\LobsterTwofamily}\selectfont}
```

the `\MakeUppercase` macro will capitalize also the `Lbstr-LF` string. And indeed the warning is about

```
OT1/LBSTR-LF/m/sl
```

whereas the family name is `Lbstr-LF`.

I'd not load the LobsterTwo package, it's simpler to provide the *robust* definition yourself.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareRobustCommand*\LobsterTwo{\fontfamily{Lbstr-LF}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\LTtext}{\LobsterTwo}

\begin{document}

\chapter{\LTtext{Test} and normal type}
\section{Test section}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

This way the substitution of slanted type with italic type will work. You can also use `\LobsterTwo` if you prefer, but I'd not.

[image]

[image]